# OpenGL 3D texture generation crash

Tags: macos, opengl

Im doing some work with 3D textures and i've hit a bit of the snag on OSX. The code I use to generate the 3D texture works fine on Windows and LINUX, but on OSX it crashes more often than not. The code looks like so:

```
#define LUT_3D_RESOLUTION 32
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
float* buffer = new float[LUT_3D_RESOLUTION*LUT_3D_RESOLUTION*LUT_3D_RESOLUTION*4];
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)LUT_3D_RESOLUTION, (int)LUT_3D_RESOLUTION, (int)LUT_3D_RESOLUTION, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D,0,0,0,0,(int)LUT_3D_RESOLUTION,(int)LUT_3D_RESOLUTION,(int)LUT_3D_RESOLUTION,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,buffer);
glFlush();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
```

The crash occurs on the glTexSubImage3D image, and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, and the address it's trying to access is way beyond the allocated buffer.

Comment: did you try checking for errors? also moot but shouldnt you use GLfloat for portability purposes?

Comment: There appear to be about 4 or 5 typographical errors in the code you listed (all related to `LUT_3D_RESOLUTION`). Did you paste it properly?

Comment: I tried these lines of code on a Mac, and couldn't reproduce a crash. Is this the only thing you do? Or do you have some state set that might influence this? Like pixel store parameters? Or an unpack buffer?

Comment: Are you sure you have created a texture with glGenTextures and bound it with glBindTexture? Also is GL_RGBA a valid internal format? Shouldn't it be GL_RGBA8?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH has been previously set to an non zero value. Setting this value to zero fixed the problem. Thanks to those who replied. –